# Windowsphone Start button handler

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Well, I’m developing a small game for Windowsphone (with Silverlight). That way, I’d like how could I handle the Start button event? 
Apparently, is not possible to override the Application_Deactivated method, right? Hence, even if I create a method and call it inside Apllication_Deactivated, the game would be finished anyways.

I’d like to show a Canvas, like: Are you show you want to leave the Game. Pretty basic. I’ve done that on return button. So, how could I make the same on Start button?

Cheers,

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: You can't.

Microsoft states that it is not the developers choice to handle what happens when the start button is pressed. What you should do is handle the event and save user state, then reload the state when the user navigates back to the application.